# re.search not giving output with multiple groups

Tags: python, regex

i need to print all the matches from given input file in a dictionary.

======================================================================
Input file:

> RT-01#sh version 
>   Cisco IOS Software, C3900 Software (C3900-UNIVERSALK9-M), Version 15.7(3)M4b, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1) Technical Support: http://www.cisco.com/techsupport Copyright (c) 1986-2019 by Cisco Systems, Inc. Compiled Tue 07-May-19 18:56 by prod_rel_team
>
> ROM: System Bootstrap, Version 15.0(1r)M16, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)
>
> RT-01 uptime is 1 week, 6 days, 18 hours, 45 minutes System returned to ROM by reload at 14:40:06 UTC Thu Aug 22 2019 System restarted at 14:42:15 UTC Thu Aug 22 2019 System image file is "flash0:c3900-universalk9-mz.SPA.157-3.M4b.bin" Last reload type: Normal Reload Last reload reason: Reload Command
>
> This product contains cryptographic features and is subject to United States and local country laws governing import, export, transfer and use. Delivery of Cisco cryptographic products does not imply third-party authority to import, export, distribute or use encryption. Importers, exporters, distributors and users are responsible for compliance with U.S. and local country laws. By using this product you agree to comply with applicable laws and regulations. If you are unable to comply with U.S. and local laws, return this product immediately.
>
> A summary of U.S. laws governing Cisco cryptographic products may be found at: http://www.cisco.com/wwl/export/crypto/tool/stqrg.html
>
> If you require further assistance please contact us by sending email to export@cisco.com.
>
> Cisco CISCO3945-CHASSIS (revision 1.0) with C3900-SPE150/K9 with 978944K/69632K bytes of memory. Processor board ID FLNARU56836 9 Gigabit Ethernet interfaces 68 terminal lines 1 Virtual Private Network (VPN) Module DRAM configuration is 72 bits wide with parity enabled. 255K bytes of non-volatile configuration memory. 255488K bytes of ATA System CompactFlash 0 (Read/Write) License Info:
>
> License UDI:
>   Device# PID SN
>   *1 C3900-SPE150/K9 FLNARU56836
>
> Suite License Information for Module:'c3900'
>   Suite Suite Current Type Suite Next reboot
>   FoundationSuiteK9 None None None securityk9 datak9
>
> AdvUCSuiteK9 None None None uck9 cme-srst cube
>
> Technology Package License Information for Module:'c3900'
>
> Technology Technology-package Technology-package
>
> Current Type Next reboot
>   ipbase ipbasek9 Permanent ipbasek9 security securityk9 Permanent securityk9 uc None None None data None None None
>
> Configuration register is 0x2102

====================================================================
CODE:

```
import re
import collections

systemfields = ["Name", "Model", "System ID", "Image"]

command = ''
name = ''
systeminfo = collections.OrderedDict()
systeminfo[name] = collections.OrderedDict(zip(systemfields, [''] * len(systemfields)))
infile = open("testfile.txt", "r")
for line in infile:
    if command == 'show version' and name != '':
    # extracts information as per patterns
        m = re.search("Processor board ID (.*)", line)
        if m:
            systeminfo[name]['System ID'] = m.group(1)
            continue
        m = re.search("Cisco\s* (.*)-CHASSIS", line)
        if m:
            systeminfo[name]['Model'] = m.group(1)
            continue
        m = re.search("^cisco (.*) processor", line)
        if m:
            systeminfo[name]['Model'] = m.group(1)
            continue
        m = re.search("^Cisco (.*) \(revision", line)
        if m:
            systeminfo[name]['Model'] = m.group(1)
            continue
        m = re.search('System image file is \"flash0:\/?(.*)\.bin\"', line)
        if m:
            systeminfo[name]['Image'] = m.group(1)
            continue
        m = re.search('System image file is \"flash:\/.*\/(.*)\.bin\"', line)
        if m:
            systeminfo[name]['Image'] = m.group(1)
            continue
        m = re.search('System image file is \"bootflash:(.*)\.bin\"', line)
        if m:
            systeminfo[name]['Image'] = m.group(1)
            continue
        m = re.search('System image file is \"sup-bootflash:(.*)\.bin\"', line)
        if m:
            systeminfo[name]['Image'] = m.group(1)
            continue

print(systeminfo)
```

Expected output:

[('Name', 'RT-01'), ('Model', 'CISCO3945'), ('System ID', 'FLNARU56836'), ('Image', 'c3900-universalk9-mz.SPA.157-3.M4b.bin')])

Comment: `if command == 'show version' and name != '':` is not allowing any of your actual regex code to execute, because neither half of that condition is true.

Comment: Yeah I tried removing and condition still no output.

Comment: `RT-01` and `FLNARU56836` are listed multiple times. Is there any logic to it which one to match?

Comment: Name coming before # is Rt01 and after  Processor board ID I need that this all I need with match groups

Comment: @naruto I have added an answer with some explanations.

Comment: @Thefourthbird i had got the output ,how ever my issue is if i have text file with multiple output in that text file if i match the sh version in the above text i need to fetch those outputs ('Name', 'RT-01'), ('Model', 'CISCO3945'), ('System ID', 'FLNARU56836'), ('Image', 'c3900-universalk9-mz.SPA.157-3.M4b.bin')]

Answer (score 2):

Using [re.search](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search) will return first location where the regular expression pattern produces a match, and return a corresponding match object.

You could get the 4 matches using a capturing group which you could use in your code.

A short explanation about the patterns.

Name:

```
^([^\s#]+)#
```

- `^` Start of string
- `([^\s#]+)` Capture **group 1** Match 1+ times any char except `#` or a whitespace char
- `#` Match literally

Model:

```
^Cisco ([^-\s]+)
```

- `^` Start of string
- `Cisco`  Match literally and space
- `([^-\s]+)` Capture **group 1** Match 1+ times any char except `-` and whitespace char

System ID:

```
Processor board ID (\S+)
```

- `Processor board ID`  Match literally and space
- `(\S+)` Capture **group 1** Match 1+ times a non whitespace char

Image:

```
flash\d+:([^"]+)
```

- `flash\d+:` Match flash, 1+ digits and `:`
- `([^"]+)` Capture **group 1** Match 1+ times any char except `"`

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/ViAfSj)

For example:

```
name = re.search(r"^([^\s#]+)#", test_str, re.M)
print(name.group(1))

model = re.search(r"^Cisco ([^-\s]+)", test_str, re.M)
print(model.group(1))

systemId = re.search(r"Processor board ID (\S+)", test_str)
print(systemId.group(1))

image = re.search(r'"flash\d+:([^"]+)', test_str)
print(image.group(1))
```

Output

```
RT-01
CISCO3945
FLNARU56836
c3900-universalk9-mz.SPA.157-3.M4b.bin
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that maybe an expression similar to the following might be somewhat close to the desired output and you might just want to add some left and right boundaries for those you wish to capture, such as:

```
(?<=ID\s)[A-Z0-9]{11}|(?<=Cisco\s)[A-Z0-9]{9}|^[A-Z]{2,}-[0-9]{2,}(?=\suptime)|(?<=")[^:]+:[a-z0-9]+-[a-z0-9]+-[^"]+
```

#### Test

```
import re

string = """

RT-01 uptime is 1 week, 6 days, 18 hours, 45 minutes System returned to ROM by reload at 14:40:06 UTC Thu Aug 22 2019 System restarted at 14:42:15 UTC Thu Aug 22 2019 System image file is "flash0:c3900-universalk9-mz.SPA.157-3.M4b.bin" Last reload type: Normal Reload Last reload reason: Reload Command

This product contains cryptographic features and is subject to United States and local country laws governing import, export, transfer and use. Delivery of Cisco cryptographic products does not imply third-party authority to import, export, distribute or use encryption. Importers, exporters, distributors and users are responsible for compliance with U.S. and local country laws. By using this product you agree to comply with applicable laws and regulations. If you are unable to comply with U.S. and local laws, return this product immediately.

A summary of U.S. laws governing Cisco cryptographic products may be found at: http://www.cisco.com/wwl/export/crypto/tool/stqrg.html

If you require further assistance please contact us by sending email to export@cisco.com.

Cisco CISCO3945-CHASSIS (revision 1.0) with C3900-SPE150/K9 with 978944K/69632K bytes of memory. Processor board ID FLNARU56836 9 Gigabit Ethernet interfaces 68 terminal lines 1 Virtual Private Network (VPN) Module DRAM configuration is 72 bits wide with parity enabled. 255K bytes of non-volatile configuration memory. 255488K bytes of ATA System CompactFlash 0 (Read/Write) License Info:

"""

print(re.findall(r'(?<=ID\s)[A-Z0-9]{11}|(?<=Cisco\s)[A-Z0-9]{9}|^[A-Z]{2,}-[0-9]{2,}(?=\suptime)|(?<=")[^:]+:[a-z0-9]+-[a-z0-9]+-[^"]+', string, re.M))
```

#### Output

```
['RT-01', 'flash0:c3900-universalk9-mz.SPA.157-3.M4b.bin', 'CISCO3945', 'FLNARU56836']
```

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/h4IDU3/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/h4IDU3/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---

Comment: That I have tried ,I want to get that using re.search and groups